# OneToMany & ManyToOne foreign key not intialized on persist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a problem ... that seems pretty usual, but actually i don't find solution.
I feel that it is something stupid but i cna't find what.

I have one class Post

```
@Entity(name = "PersistencePostEntity")
@Table(name = "post")
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "post-with-rating",
    attributeNodes = {
        @NamesAttributeNode("rating")
    }
)
public class PostEntity extends AbstractAuditingEntity {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "childPost", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @Where(clause = "archived='false'")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<PostRelationEntity> clusterParents = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

and a PostRelationEntity class

```
@Entity(name = "PersistencePostRelationEntity")
@Table(name = "post_relation")
public class PostRelationEntity {

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "child_post_id")
     @JsonBackReference
     private PostEntity childPost;

}
```

(I've selected the interesting fields cause the class are pretty long)

I would like that when i initialize a post with in it a list of relations in the clusterParenst field (relations without childPost init) the relations are automatically persisted with the childPost id inited with the newly created post.

The OneToMany / ManyToOne relation should do it but it doesn't.
Any suggestion ? I haven't do Spring since a few months and i'm not finding my problem.

Thank you by advance for your answers

Comment: Is Your code inside a public repository (like gitHub)? If yes, can you post the link here?

Comment: It is recommended to [synchronize both sides](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/) of relationship.

Comment: Hi, no, it's not it's a private repo that i can't share.
And @StefanGolubović both sides are synchronized, because it's a relation between two posts. And there is the clusterParents and the clusterChild (which is the other side of the relation)

Comment: @BenoitBonavia can you share code how you synchronize both sides? Based on code shared in question, I would argue that you're missing utility methods for adding/removing `clusterParent` in `Post` entity. For example, `public void addClusterParent(PostRelatedEntity entity) { clusterParents.add(entity); entity.setChildPost(this); }`

Comment: You have the code it's syncrhonized both side because PostEntity is both sides. I just have a second field clusterChilds which is the second side in PostEntity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a solution, when i'm saving the post with the PostRepository, i'm also persisting manually the relations with their own Repo. This is simplyer and cleaner

Answer (score 0):

I used to resolve it by manually setting the references of the objects, i.e

```
PostEntity postEntity = new PostEntity();
PostRelationEntity postRelationEntity = new PostRelationEntity();
postRelationEntity.setChildPost(postEntity);
postEntity.add(postRelationEntity);
```

Comment: I can't do that, the child post IS the post i'm trying to create. So it doesn't have id yet. I would have to save it twice if i wanted to do this. And it's not a good practice.

Comment: the id should be assigned by Spring and you don't need to save it twice, you just save the PostEntity